# Print IEnumerable As String Received From Regex.Matches

Tags: c#

So I have a this following code to match a RegEx Pattern.

```
string data = "1463735418 Bytes: 0 Time: 4.297 1463735424 Time: 2.205 1466413696 Time: 2.225 1466413699 1466413702 1466413705 1466413708 1466413711 1466413714 1466413717 1466413720 Bytes: 7037 Time: 59.320 ......";

string pattern = @"
    (?<=Bytes:\s)(?<Bytes>\d+)   # Lookbehind for the bytes
    |                            # Or
    (?<=Time:\s)(?<Time>[\d.]+)  # Lookbehind for time
    |                            # Or
    (?<Integer>\d+)              # most likely its just an integer.
    ";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => new
                   {
                       IsInteger = mt.Groups["Integer"].Success,
                       IsTime = mt.Groups["Time"].Success,
                       IsByte = mt.Groups["Bytes"].Success,
                       strMatch = mt.Groups[0].Value,
                       AsInt  = mt.Groups["Integer"].Success ? int.Parse(mt.Groups["Integer"].Value) : -1,
                       AsByte = mt.Groups["Bytes"].Success ? int.Parse(mt.Groups["Bytes"].Value) : -1,
                       AsTime = mt.Groups["Time"].Success ? double.Parse(mt.Groups["Time"].Value) : -1.0,
                   })
```

How do I print it out as a string, that is the matched data from the RegEx?

That is, I need my result viz. as string:

```
Expected Output: 
0, 4.297 
7037, 59.320
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than the choose-your-own-adventure link clicking exercise. Perhaps rewording "that is where the matched data" might be useful too.

Comment: In other words, you should spend the effort so that I can copy, paste, and run your code with minimal effort on my part.

Comment: Absolutely sorry, editing now.

Comment: Are you wanting to print the result of the "matched data from the RegEx" or from the `.Select` method?

Comment: @Enigmativity Both please. I have also added a sample output. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, this is a case of: I have a problem and I'll use Regex to solve it. Now I have two problems.

Comment: So, so true :( stuck with this for the last hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your sample I assume you only want to match "Byte: x Time: y" for you're output.

You could easily achieve that this way:

```
        string pattern = @"
                        Bytes:\s
                        (?<Bytes>\d+)
                        \s+
                        Time:\s
                        (?<Time>[\d.]+)";

        var matches = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
             .OfType<Match>()
             .Select(mt => mt.Groups["Bytes"] + " " + mt.Groups["Time"]);

        string result = String.Join("\n", matches);
```

Otherwise you could store the MatchCollection from the `Regex.Matches()` in a variable and run both linq expressions separately

Comment: I get blank results!

Comment: @jeet - When I use the input from this question I get exactly the results you want. When I use the input from your previous question (i.e. separate lines) then I also get blank results. You need to make sure that you get your question right.

Comment: Ah, had a small bug. This solution is perfect and very small!

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid the use of regex then here's an alternative:

```
var results =
    lines
        .Zip(lines.Skip(1), (l0, l1) => l0.Split(':').Concat(l1.Split(':')).ToArray())
        .Where(x => x[0] == "Bytes" && x[2] == "Time")
        .Select(x => $"{int.Parse(x[1].Trim())}, {double.Parse(x[3].Trim())}");
```

That assumes your data is in lines like your previous question:

```
1463735418
Bytes: 0
Time: 4.297
1463735424
Time: 2.205
1466413696
Time: 2.225
1466413699
1466413702
1466413705
1466413708
1466413711
1466413714
1466413717
1466413720
Bytes: 7037
Time: 59.320
```

That gives the expected result:

```
0, 4.297 
7037, 59.32
```

Comment: Brilliant and fast! Thanks!